# 'Table name' could not be resolved in the current scope or context

Tags: entity-framework, dapper

I saw a similar question to this, but it involved field names and not the table name issue I'm having.

I'm trying to do a simple pull from one of my tables, but I'm encountering an error that I just can't figure out.

The error message states:

> 'StudentBilingual' could not be resolved in the current scope or context. Make sure that all referenced variables are in scope, that required schemas are loaded, and that namespaces are referenced correctly.

```
            using (CEDARSEntity entity = CEDARSEntity.CreateInstance())
            {
                entity.Connection.Open();

                var result = entity.Connection.Query<StudentBilingual>(
                                        @"select [schoolYear]
                                                ,[districtOrganizationId]
                                                ,[schoolOrganizationId]
                                                ,[locationid]
                                                ,[ssid]
                                                ,[startDate]
                                                ,[recStartDate]
                                                ,[keyHash]
                                                ,[dataHash]
                                                ,[programId]
                                                ,[districtStudentCode]
                                                ,[instructionalModelId]
                                                ,[exitDate]
                                                ,[programExitReasonId]
                                                ,[placementTestScaleScore]
                                                ,[placementTestLevelId]
                                                ,[placementTestDate]
                                                ,[initialWAPlacementDate]
                                                ,[initialUSPlacementDate]
                                                ,[numMonthsUSAttendance]
                                                ,[numMonthsNonUSEducation]
                                                ,[recEndDate]
                                                ,[programdesignation]
                                                ,[placementTestCodeId]
                                                ,[gradeLevelAtPlacementId]
                                        from StudentBilingual 
                                        Where schoolYear=2011");
                entity.Connection.Close();
            }
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Is StudentBilingual the Database or a table?

Comment: StudentBilingual is a table inside of my database.  My entity object has StudentBilingual mapped as an entity type.